# Configure javascript to rise error when pass json undefined member?

Tags: javascript, json, browser

You have a json object.
By mistake you pass some element (property1) to a function and the value passed doesn't exists...

```
myFunction (json.propety1); // it must be 'property1' , with r
```

I'd like to set any configure element to say the browser "I can't pass undefined json properties, rise an error" 
I think this is not possible, is't it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: inside the function check argument is undefined and throw error

Answer (score 0):

in myfunction you can check for undefined and then do something

like

```
function myFunction(jsonproperty){
    if(jsonproperty === undefined){
      //do something with the DOM to pass whatever you wanna say in the browser
    }
}
```

Is that what you were trying to do? You could also throw an exception like this:

```
throw "json property was undefined"
```

but you would only see that in some kind of js debugger console. Nowadays all browser have one. Usually accessible with "F12"

Comment: Yes , I now that. But I 'd want an automatic behaviour. Who wants to use undefined values ?  I don't ....

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic behaviour"? Do you want javascript to always throw an error when a undefined parameter is passed? The best way to automate it, would be to create another function "checkParameters" so you could call that at the start of other functions

Comment: if you want to use 'default' values when passed arg is undefined, you can try something like: jsonproperty = jsonproperty || 'myDefaultValue'; Everything else is fine here what juli0r mentioned.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work like that. It is a loosely typed language so you can pass any type to the function. You can even call a function that expects 3 parameters to be passed, without even specifying any. In short: what you want to do is not possible in javascript without any special framework/library that would take care of that. That's it. That's why we don't (can't) answer your question.